# voting system with ajax and php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Thanks for reading.

I'm trying to improve so I'm doing an example project to improve. I made a simple. voting system. I have number of contents which displayed by php each of them have up or down vote  button. by the way I use twitter bootstrap.

this is the html code:

```
<html>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-mini upvote" id="'.$data['ContentID'].'">
    <i class="icon-arrow-up"></i>
</button>

    <span id="voteresponse">'.$data['VoteSum'].'</span>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-mini downvote" id="'.$data['ContentID'].'">
    <i class="icon-arrow-down"></i>
</button>
</html>
```

the problem is when I lick up button which is `class="upvote"` all other buttons does same thing. because the data populated by php there are many of them.

this is my javascript.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

              $('.upvote').click( function(event) {

              event.preventDefault();

              $("#voteresponse").html('');
              var voteID = $(".upvote").first().attr("id");

                $.ajax({
                  url: "/ajax.php?Page=votetitle",
                  type: "post",
                  dataType: "json",
                  data: {id : voteID},
                  success: function(data, textStatus){
                    if(data.success == 'true'){
                      $('#voteresponse').html(data.message);
                      return true;
                    }else{
                      $('#voteresponse').popover({
                        title: 'Hata!',
                        content: data.message 
                      });
                    }
                  },
                  error:function(){
                      $('#voteresponse').popover({
                        title: 'error!',
                        content: 'Server error' 
                      });
                  }
                }); 
              });
            });
</script>
```

and the php code is just usual database request.

```
<?php

if ( $_SESSION['UserID'] <1 )
    die( print_r(json_encode(array('success'=>'false', 'message'=>'error for user!')))     );

    print_r(json_encode(array('success'=>'true', 'message'=>$_POST['id'])))

?>
```

you can see the action [here](http://test.erdemece.com/). if you click one of them all other up arrows do same thing. also is this approach right?

thanks. best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the first one "responds" when you click any of them... This is likely because of `var voteID = $(".upvote").first().attr("id");` The voteID should be something like `$(this).attr('id');` instead.

Note that you need to recognize which button was clicked, you can use for example `$(this).parent()`... That will give you to the upper DOM level of the clicked button (div `media isotope-item`) and from there you can modify only the content of that div.

Comment: Try this for a start: `var voteID = $(this).attr("id");`, that should give you the right ID, and to modify the content of the correct div, use what I wrote in the second paragraph, and modify your success callback based on it... `$(this)` selector is the key here, as it represents the clicked element.

Comment: No way... perhaps there is more of your code that you didn't show and it uses the similar first() selectors?

Comment: To see how it works, try to launch this code from the console: `$('.upvote').click( function(event) {alert($(this).attr('id'));})` It's a super-simplified version of what you need to do - it alerts the id of **clicked** button.

Comment: no sorry. I'm trying to figure it out. my English not so good. so, I'm trying understand your explanation:) which is very easy I suppose but let's see. as far as I understand $(this) is my unique ID which is ContentID. That's is the reference but I'm a noob to javascript syntax so I'm not sure where should I add parent() function. still trying:)

Comment: no, no, `$(this)` is used in the `click` function, and it represents the clicked element (the correct .upvote button, in your case)... and you might not need `parent()` at all, I just gave it to you so you know how to access the parent element of the clicked one.

Comment: I thin I done it. I added this  `<span id="voteresponse'.$data['ContentID'].'">6549</span> ` to my html code and change the success event to this.  `$('#voteresponse'+voteID).html(data.message); ` do you think is this right. it seems it's working.

Comment: thank you very much. have a nice day! learned something new today.

Answer (score 3):

try changing

```
var voteID = $(".upvote").first().attr("id");
```

to this

```
var voteID = $(this).first().attr("id");
```

or

```
var voteID = $(this).attr("id");
```